# problems with ices

Tags: streaming, ices

I am trying to [compile](https://gist.github.com/bdsatish/ea812f765e4c3124aebb#mp3-streaming-with-ices0) ices but I get **this error when I execute `make`**

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

---

@Martin: Thanks for your interest, when I ran `./configure` I got this error:

```
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
```

I have a file called Makefile.in and other file called Makefile.am

Comment: Is there a file called Makefile?  Were there any errors when you ran ./configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You need a C++ compiler and run `./configure` before `make`

---

1. Install a C++ compiler

   ```
   sudo apt-get install g++
   ```
2. Follow these steps

   ```
   cd
   sudo apt-get install libmp3lame-dev libxml2-dev libshout-dev libvorbis-dev
   wget http://downloads.us.xiph.org/releases/ices/ices-0.4.tar.gz
   tar xf ices-0.4.tar.gz
   cd ices-0.4
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-pic --with-lame
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: @AB: I have the **gcc compiler** installed

Comment: So what.  You need g++ as well.  Did you try following these instructions?

Comment: @MartinThornton: Thanks so much guys¡¡¡¡ I only **needed to install g++** (newbie error:D)........Thanks again A.B:)